# Delco battery code

Tags: battery, maintenance

I have two new Delco batteries and the code reading methods I have seen don't seem to work. there is an etched   number in the top 7MKD27, then there is a sticker P0585 with group number on the sticker also.

Comment: Welcome to the site. It's not clear what your question is. Could you provide more details on the code reading methods you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

The ***P0585*** would be the date code. It really doesn't make sense, though. According to [this ACDelco PDF](https://www.acdelco.com/content/dam/acdelco/na/us/en/index/parts/warranty/02-pdfs/acdelco-battery-warranty-information.pdf), the P0585 indicates this battery was made in either May of 2008 or May of 2018 (05=Month; 8=Year; 5=Manufacturing plant). If these truly are brand new batteries and not 10 years old, then I'd say ACDelco is jumping the gun a little bit with their manufacture date, but it does extend the life of their warranty (which is also talked about in the PDF).